# Cassandra.yaml settings client SSL

Tags: ssl, encryption, cassandra, keystore, truststore

Please help me to understand one thing.
There is block of settings in cassandra for client's path of keystore and truststore SSL. I.e. I should configure in server node of Cassandra paths to  CLIENT keystore.
But how does it work? It seems It is correct would be  locate keystore/truststore of cliet on Application host, like POD, docker or
Application server and use keystore to connect to DBMS Cassandra. How client can use
his keystore, which is located on server?

```
enabled: true
keystore: E:/apache-cassandra-2.1.4/conf/.keystore
keystore_password: cassandra
# require_client_auth: false
# Set trustore and truststore_password if require_client_auth is true
# truststore: conf/.truststore
# truststore_password: cassandra
# More advanced defaults below:
# protocol: TLS
# algorithm: SunX509
# store_type: JKS
# cipher_suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
```

Answer (score 1):

This block is used to check that the clients have valid certificate (that it's signed by trusted authority), use correct cipher, etc., or even enforce that client's certificate is registered in the truststore (if you set `require_client_auth: true`).

Basically, what you need is that your clients did use certificate that is signed by valid authority, known by Cassandra.  DataStax has [very detailed documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/security/6.7/security/encryptClientNodeSSL.html) on how to setup client-to-server SSL.  Cassandra site also [includes a lot](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/security.html), but some things could be specific to 4.0 release.

Comment: thanks ,  i will try comment (#) paths to client's keystore\truststore.